# J2ME Ticker at custom location on the screen

Tags: mobile, java-me, midp, lcdui

How to get the ticker at the middle or at custom location on the screen?

I think the normal ticker will place a ticker on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own implementation, or use something that wraps the [LCDUI Ticker](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Ticker.html) such as LWUIT.  If you don't it will be completely implementation dependent where the ticker goes, you have no control over it.